# SQL Server 2008 Trigger to Update/Insert/Delete From Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a table `UserInfoComputed` whose data comes from `UserInfo` and `UserInfoComputed` also have foreign key constraint to `UserCompany`.

I have a trigger on `UserInfo` which inserts/updates/deletes rows into `UserInfoComputed`

Here is my `UserInfoComputed` table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfoComputed ](
        [id]  AS (CONVERT([bigint],replace([law_id],'LAW',''),(0))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
        [company_id] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
        [first_name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
        [last_name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
        [law_id] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
        [type] [smallint] NULL,
        [dtype]  AS (case [TYPE] when (1) then 'Corporate' else 'Non-Corporate' end)        PERSISTED NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_UserInfoComputed] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    [id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserInfoComputed]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT    [FK668581C04AA07B12]     FOREIGN KEY([company_id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[UserCompany] ([id])
    GO
```

Here is my `UserInfo` table

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInfo](
    [ID] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyID] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [Status] [char](4) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_UserInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
     ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
```

Here is the `UserCompany` table

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserCompany](
        [ID] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [ShortName] [varchar](25) NULL,
        [Type] [smallint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_UserCompany] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
```

The type values are either 1 or 2 or 3

Here is my trigger on `UserInfo` table

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ReconcileUserInfoComputed]
   ON [dbo].[UserInformation]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 -- exit trigger when zero records affected
BEGIN
    RETURN
END
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
    BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
        BEGIN
            --UPDATE
            UPDATE [dbo].[UserInformationComputed]
            SET -- use new values from inserted 
            first_name = (SELECT FirstName FROM inserted),
            last_name = (SELECT LastName FROM inserted),
            law_id = (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
            WHERE law_id = (SELECT ID FROM deleted)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --INSERT
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserInfoComputed] (first_name,last_name, law_id)
            SELECT FirstName, LastName, ID FROM inserted
        END
    END
    ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN
        --DELETE
        DELETE FROM [dbo].[UserInfoComputed]
        WHERE law_id = (SELECT id FROM deleted)
    END 
GO
```

Is there a way to insert or update type value from `UserCompany` into `UserInfoComputed` table in `ReconcileUserInfoComputed` trigger?

Comment: If all of these tables are in the same database have you considered using [`Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620086/CASCADE-in-SQL-Server-with-example)

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. WHich of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT id FROM deleted` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!